# Installing Akka for Java in Eclipse (Kubuntu)

Tags: java, eclipse, akka

I wish to use the Akka actor modules.
I am using Eclipse in Kubuntu.
I downloaded the .zip archive from the akka website, went to:

```
Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add External Jar
```

and added all jars that came with the zip.

In my code, I do:

```
import akka.actor.Actor;
import akka.event.EventHandler;

class MyActor extends Actor{




}
```

and I get a straight error in line:

```
class myActor extends Actor{
```

Error is:

```
The type Actor cannot be the superclass of MyActor; a superclass must be a class
```

But isn't Actor supposed to be a class? At least that is what all the tutorials say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `akka.actor.UntypedActor`. From the [reference documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/untyped-actors.html):

> Actor in Java are implemented by extending the UntypedActor class and
>   implementing the onReceive method. This method takes the message as a
>   parameter.

Here's an example: https://github.com/alexaverbuch/akka_chat_java/blob/master/src/main/java/chat/actors/Session.java